# Drop shadow on text

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I am looking to add drop shadow to text on an image using PHP.

I am aware on how to add text to images and how some libraries allow you to add block shadowing, but I cannot see any which allow you to add a faded drop shadow.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14):

What you want is Imagick::shadowImage ( float $opacity , float $sigma , int $x , int $y )

Here's an example where I put a drop shadow on some text and then superimpose that on a background image...

```
$background_layer = new Imagick('poster_pic_01.jpg'); # background image

$text_layer = new Imagick('transparent400.png'); # empty transparent png of the same size
$text_layer->annotateImage( $ImagickDraw, $pad_left, $pad_top, 0, "Your text here" );

/* create drop shadow on it's own layer */
$shadow_layer = $text_layer->clone(); 
$shadow_layer->setImageBackgroundColor( new ImagickPixel( 'black' ) ); 
$shadow_layer->shadowImage( 75, 5, 5, 5 ); 

/* composite original text_layer onto shadow_layer */
$shadow_layer->compositeImage( $text_layer, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0 ); 

/* composite shadow_layer (which now has text AND the shadow) onto image_layer */
$background_layer->compositeImage( $shadow_layer, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0 );
```

Hope this helps,

Roger

Answer (score 2):

GD can't do this out of the box. If you can, use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). Examples on how to do shaped shadows [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#shadow_shape).

Comment: How would I go about using the above command line bits in PHP, I can't see anything on http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php that would help me.

Comment: @user good question. I don't know the PHP extension so I don't know - *maybe* using [`ShadowImage`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-shadowimage.php), but I'm not sure.