# PHP Image Text Shadowing

Tags: php, image, image-processing

Can anyone tell me how I can make font shadows like this in a php-generated image?

[image: Screenshot]

BTW: Anyone knows the name of this font?

Comment: Try this site to identify the font http://www.whatfontis.com/ . Even though not exactly the same, you a close ones which looks similar.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289297/drop-shadow-on-text

Comment: Thank you all for the font names :P But that wasn't my main question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this method. But I think you can try. I'm keeping this as simple as possible.

Shadows is nothing but grey or black shade that comes at angle with respect to the imagined light source in 2D or 3D images .

So to simply make a shadow effect on a text in an image using php, I would suggest that first you print that text in the desired image file in light grey color. Then with an offset to left, right, top or with combinations of these, print the text in the desired color overlapping the previously printed text. Now you will be able to see some shadow effect.

This is a minimalistic simple answer anyone can try. This can be done using GD library which already included in the php package. You won't need any external libraries.

Answer (score -1):

This font is called `Bardot Medium`